# Is it possible to disable input[type=image] with no ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable a form input of type image, but it does not have an ID.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does it have specific class or position?

Comment: Is there more than one of these on the form?  Can you post your markup?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[type=image]').prop("disabled",true)
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OgaQoCEw/1/edit)

**or simply like:**

```
$(':image').prop("disabled",true)
```

[DEMO 2](http://jsbin.com/OgaQoCEw/2/edit)

if you need to disable **only the image inputs that have NO id**

```
$(':image:not([id])').prop("disabled",true)
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OgaQoCEw/3/edit)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to disable all inputs with the type `image` that specifically *do not* have an `id` attribute, you can do this:

```
$('input[type="image"]').not('[id]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Otherwise, you'll have to figure out how you can identify the particular field you're looking for.